# How to avoid Eclipse wrapping if multiple statements

Tags: java, eclipse

Well, I have this piece of code:

```
if (emailEditText.getText().toString().equals("") || passwordEditText.getText().equals(""))
 {
      //Do something.
 }
```

But when formatting the code, Eclipse wraps the code to this:

```
if (emailEditText.getText().toString().equals("")
        || passwordEditText.getText().equals(""))
      {
         //Do something.
      }
```

And I want to keep it like the first example. So, does somebody know how to keep multiple  "if" conditions in the same code line.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The line is wrapped because it exceeds the maximum size of 80 characters which is set by default. If you want to set another limit, go to Windows - > Preferences -> Java -> Code style -> Formatter -> Select `Eclipse` profile and click Edit (or you can use your own profile) -> at the opened dialog open `Line wrapping` tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Window menu, goto Preferences. Select Java, then Code Style. The options for formatting options are in Formatter.